# Unable to add Facebook Comments plugin to website

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add the Facebook comments plugin to a website, but no matter what I try it just appears as an empty div.

First attempt I followed the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

In my body I have

```
    <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '551918012565032',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v12.0'
    });
  };
</script>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

and in the HTML of the page I have

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://adventureswithanthony.com/test-fb-comments" data-width="100" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

But it shows up as a blank div. I then tried a few different Wordpress add-ons that were supposed to simplify the process, but again, it's just a blank div. My test page below has two comment boxes supposed to appear, one created using a plugin and the other using manual HTML, but both are just blank.

Test page: http://adventureswithanthony.com/test-fb-comments/

Answer (score 0):

I woke up this morning and refreshed the page, and the comments box is showing up now. I guess Facebook may have a setup period after an App ID is created before it can actually be used.